# opencv2 can build using cmake but not in CLion "build" functionality?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, clion

I'm very confused why I can use `cmake` in commandline to build a C++ program, but cannot build the program in CLion with its "build" functionality.

This is my `CMakeLists.txt` file. I am trying to build a simple image classification program with OpenCV, the tutorial is [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d5/de7/tutorial_dnn_googlenet.html).

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
project(opencvdnn )

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

add_executable(caffe caffe.cpp)
target_link_libraries(caffe ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

**case 1:**

I build directly in the command line successfully with the following commands and results:

```
user:/DATA/opencvdnn/build$ cmake ../CMakeLists.txt

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /media/yuqiong/DATA/opencvdnn
```

**Case 2**

I use the `build` functionality in my CLion IDE, which failed, claiming it cannot find a certain library.

```
/opt/clion-2018.2.5/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --build /media/yuqiong/DATA/opencvdnn --target caffe -- -j 6
Scanning dependencies of target caffe
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/caffe.cpp.o
/media/yuqiong/DATA/opencvdnn/caffe.cpp:5:27: fatal error: opencv2/dnn.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/caffe.cpp.o' failed
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/caffe.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'caffe' failed
make: *** [caffe] Error 2
```

My question is why would that be? Is CLion not using the same CMake with the `cmake` tool? Thanks!

If helps, here is my directory structure:

```
├── build
├── bvlc_googlenet.caffemodel
├── bvlc_googlenet.prototxt
├── caffe.cpp
├── cmake-build-debug
│   ├── CMakeCache.txt
│   ├── CMakeFiles
│   │   ├── 3.12.3
│   │   │   ├── CMakeCCompiler.cmake
│   │   │   ├── CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
│   │   │   ├── CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_C.bin
│   │   │   ├── CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_CXX.bin
│   │   │   ├── CMakeSystem.cmake
│   │   │   ├── CompilerIdC
│   │   │   │   ├── a.out
│   │   │   │   ├── CMakeCCompilerId.c
│   │   │   │   └── tmp
│   │   │   ├── CompilerIdCUDA
│   │   │   │   ├── CMakeCUDACompilerId.cu
│   │   │   │   └── tmp
│   │   │   └── CompilerIdCXX
│   │   │       ├── a.out
│   │   │       ├── CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
│   │   │       └── tmp
│   │   ├── caffe.dir
│   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   ├── CXX.includecache
│   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   ├── depend.internal
│   │   │   ├── depend.make
│   │   │   ├── flags.make
│   │   │   ├── link.txt
│   │   │   └── progress.make
│   │   ├── clion-environment.txt
│   │   ├── clion-log.txt
│   │   ├── cmake.check_cache
│   │   ├── CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
│   │   ├── CMakeError.log
│   │   ├── CMakeOutput.log
│   │   ├── CMakeTmp
│   │   ├── feature_tests.bin
│   │   ├── feature_tests.c
│   │   ├── feature_tests.cxx
│   │   ├── Makefile2
│   │   ├── Makefile.cmake
│   │   ├── opencvdnn.dir
│   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   ├── depend.make
│   │   │   ├── flags.make
│   │   │   ├── link.txt
│   │   │   └── progress.make
│   │   ├── Progress
│   │   │   ├── 1
│   │   │   └── count.txt
│   │   ├── progress.marks
│   │   └── TargetDirectories.txt
│   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── opencvdnn.cbp
├── CMakeCache.txt
├── CMakeFiles
│   ├── 3.12.3
│   │   ├── CMakeCCompiler.cmake
│   │   ├── CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
│   │   ├── CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_C.bin
│   │   ├── CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_CXX.bin
│   │   ├── CMakeSystem.cmake
│   │   ├── CompilerIdC
│   │   │   ├── a.out
│   │   │   ├── CMakeCCompilerId.c
│   │   │   └── tmp
│   │   └── CompilerIdCXX
│   │       ├── a.out
│   │       ├── CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
│   │       └── tmp
│   ├── 3.5.1
│   │   ├── CMakeCCompiler.cmake
│   │   ├── CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
│   │   ├── CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_C.bin
│   │   ├── CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_CXX.bin
│   │   ├── CMakeSystem.cmake
│   │   ├── CompilerIdC
│   │   │   ├── a.out
│   │   │   └── CMakeCCompilerId.c
│   │   └── CompilerIdCXX
│   │       ├── a.out
│   │       └── CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
│   ├── caffe.dir
│   │   ├── build.make
│   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   ├── depend.make
│   │   ├── flags.make
│   │   ├── link.txt
│   │   └── progress.make
│   ├── clion-environment.txt
│   ├── cmake.check_cache
│   ├── CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
│   ├── CMakeOutput.log
│   ├── CMakeTmp
│   ├── feature_tests.bin
│   ├── feature_tests.c
│   ├── feature_tests.cxx
│   ├── Makefile2
│   ├── Makefile.cmake
│   ├── progress.marks
│   └── TargetDirectories.txt
├── cmake_install.cmake
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── Makefile
├── opencvdnn.cbp
├── space_shuttle.jpg
└── synset_words.txt
```

This is the source code, it basically just reads a `caffe` model and use it on an image.

```
#include <opencv2/dnn.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/utils/trace.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::dnn;
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
/* Find best class for the blob (i. e. class with maximal probability) */
static void getMaxClass(const Mat &probBlob, int *classId, double *classProb)
{
    Mat probMat = probBlob.reshape(1, 1); //reshape the blob to 2x1000 matrix
    Point classNumber;
    minMaxLoc(probMat, NULL, classProb, NULL, &classNumber);
    *classId = classNumber.x;
}
static std::vector<String> readClassNames(const char *filename = "synset_words.txt")
{
    std::vector<String> classNames;
    std::ifstream fp(filename);
    if (!fp.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "File with classes labels not found: " << filename << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    std::string name;
    while (!fp.eof())
    {
        std::getline(fp, name);
        if (name.length())
            classNames.push_back( name.substr(name.find(' ')+1) );
    }
    fp.close();
    return classNames;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    CV_TRACE_FUNCTION();
    String modelTxt = "bvlc_googlenet.prototxt";
    String modelBin = "bvlc_googlenet.caffemodel";
    String imageFile = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : "space_shuttle.jpg";
    Net net;
    try {
        net = dnn::readNetFromCaffe(modelTxt, modelBin);
    }
    catch (cv::Exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        if (net.empty())
        {
            std::cerr << "Can't load network by using the following files: " << std::endl;
            std::cerr << "prototxt:   " << modelTxt << std::endl;
            std::cerr << "caffemodel: " << modelBin << std::endl;
            std::cerr << "bvlc_googlenet.caffemodel can be downloaded here:" << std::endl;
            std::cerr << "http://dl.caffe.berkeleyvision.org/bvlc_googlenet.caffemodel" << std::endl;
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    Mat img = imread(imageFile);
    if (img.empty())
    {
        std::cerr << "Can't read image from the file: " << imageFile << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    //GoogLeNet accepts only 224x224 BGR-images
    Mat inputBlob = blobFromImage(img, 1.0f, Size(224, 224),
                                  Scalar(104, 117, 123), false);   //Convert Mat to batch of images
    Mat prob;
    cv::TickMeter t;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        CV_TRACE_REGION("forward");
        net.setInput(inputBlob, "data");        //set the network input
        t.start();
        prob = net.forward("prob");                          //compute output
        t.stop();
    }
    int classId;
    double classProb;
    getMaxClass(prob, &classId, &classProb);//find the best class
    std::vector<String> classNames = readClassNames();
    std::cout << "Best class: #" << classId << " '" << classNames.at(classId) << "'" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Probability: " << classProb * 100 << "%" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Time: " << (double)t.getTimeMilli() / t.getCounter() << " ms (average from " << t.getCounter() << " iterations)" << std::endl;
    return 0;
} //main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid your first approach using command line did not work. cmake will only ever create make files. Its the make command that actually builds the target. Your clion output suggests that clion was able to successfully generate the make files, but was unable to build. I would expect identical error if you tried to do a make manually via command line.

If you can build camke project via command line, it should 100% of the time build in clion as well.

I would also recommend checking if you have opencv2 installed on your system. Check if you have a folder /usr/include/opencv or if it is /usr/include/opencv2. Since your find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED) succeeded, it is certain that you have a local installation.

Another way is to look for the file CMakeCache.txt. If you search for opencv in it, you will find the some OpenCV vars set in it. That should give you a clue.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question! The first method using `cmake` actually worked later when I run `make` in the build folder. Your advice on `CMakeCache.txt` is very helpful as I found I have two opencv installed on my computer, and the `CMakeCache.txt` that CLion is using points to a different location than the one generated by `cmake`. I'll further look into it. Thanks!